Change Paginated Blog Canonicals
I have a Wordpress website, with Elementor and Yoast.
For my blog, I use an Elementor widget to display my posts on a custom template, the ‘Maple Grid’ widget.
However, I have a canonical problem on the blog's pagination pages -probably caused by Yoast.
Since all my pages /blog/page/2/, /blog/page/3/ ... are canonicalised to the main page /blog/.
I'd like each page to be self canonical.
I have seen on forums that I could use wpseo_canonical to change the canonicals. But I'm not a technical expert on wordpress.
That's why I'm asking for your help to explain to me step by step how to implement this canonical function. And if you have any other suggestions for fixing this problem, I'd like to hear from you!
Thanks in advance for your help :) !

wpseo_canonical() isn't a WordPress function. If I had to guess, I'd say it's a Yoast function. You'll need to contact Yoast's support team about this; third-party plugin support is off topic here.
